# Will adding an additional graphic card make it possible to use one more monitor in my Windows setup?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I do have an older NVIDIA GeForce GTX 670 graphic card, that has output for 2 monitors and I am using this and "Extending" my displays in Windows 10. This works fine, but I actually do have 3 monitors at my work setup (and a switch box), so I am wondering if I just can buy an additional graphic card and mount it in my desktop computer - and then extend the 3rd monitor also in Windows?

Would this work? :-)

Comment: You could SLI connect another GTX 670 to achieve this.  It was all the rage "back in the day".  I am not sure about a non-related 2nd card.

Comment: You are probably right, but not sure how easy it is to find the same graphics card with "Scalable Link Interface" (SLI), as they are for sure not produced any more :-)